# HTML and Script not show in my wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm using a custom theme option framework on my theme. I have been integrated everything, but in textarea when paste and try to save option it automatic remove HTML codes and `<script>` only text and `<>` are remain. Text showing in my website source page here http://www.wrock.org/ I don't know how to resolve this problem.

Also there is some google tracking code, and when I explored the source I found the following

```
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    /* Show analytics code in footer */
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

function wrockmetro_analytics() {
    $shortname = wrockmetro_get_option('of_shortname');
    $output = wrockmetro_get_option($shortname . 'wrock_analytics');
    if ($output <> "")
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>" . stripslashes($output) . "</script>\n";
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'wrockmetro_analytics');
```

**Textarea code from OptionInterface.php**

```
// Textarea
        case 'textarea':
            $cols = '8';
            $ta_value = '';
            if (isset($value['options'])) {
                $ta_options = $value['options'];
                if (isset($ta_options['cols'])) {
                    $cols = $ta_options['cols'];
                } else {
                    $cols = '8';
                }
            }
            $val = stripslashes($val);
            $output .= '<textarea id="' . esc_attr($value['id']) . '" class="of-input" name="' . esc_attr($option_name . '[' . $value['id'] . ']') . '" cols="' . esc_attr($cols) . '" rows="8">' . esc_textarea($val) . '</textarea>';
            break;
```

Comment: Hi, you can't always insert html directly into a page as wordpress automatically removes it. It's a little unclear what the textbox code is used for, can you please clarify. Also the google analytics code is added through the function you posted. Basically it adds the code to the footer of your website.

Comment: ok i found problem  in options-sanitize.php  code here /* Textarea */

function of_sanitize_textarea($input) {
    global $allowedposttags;
    $output = wp_kses($input, $allowedposttags);
    return $output;
}

add_filter('of_sanitize_textarea', 'of_sanitize_textarea');

Comment: I believe you're trying to disable the wpautop function. I wrote a post about this not too long ago, here's the [post](http://goofycode.com/disable-wpautop-on-specific-postspages/255/)

Comment: i fount a script but it still urls not work  for example google adsense code url has been removed   check this script and tell how to enable all codes html as well as script http://pastebin.com/ck6Y4U5M

Comment: Hi, it's normally a bad idea to allow scripts to be included, take for example a script that redirects the user to a "bad" website. You'd be better off inserting the scripts the same way the google analytics code has been added.